# eID REST interface with authentication in Typo3

Tags: rest, authentication, typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm providing an eID page as an REST interface. Now I want to protect this page with an API key or similar. How can this be achieved in Typo3 8.7?

Actually it looks like this can only be done by logging in via frontend (FE) or backend (BE) and check the login status in the eID controller class.

Answer (score 2):

For TYPO3 v8, you should check out the EXT:restler extension instead of using eID.

eID is meant for calls where you have to do basically everything on your own.

For TYPO3 v9, the PSR-15 middleware concept allows to individually build custom REST APIs and integrations with other solutions like SlimPHP:  https://github.com/b13/slimphp-bridge

Comment: Can't find a way to use authentication in restler too. So this doesn't answer my question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect a given URL-paramter, maybe even as a post param.

Put your eID-page-configuration (typoscript) in a condition requesting this paramter to be set. Otherwise genate an error-page.

If you want to handle multiple keys (maybe from a database table) you could use a userfunc for conditions.

If you want to handle a login in the call you need to initialize more from the TYPO3 frontend. then identify the paramters from the login form (some are hidden) and provide them. AFAIK POST and GEt paramaters work.

Comment: It will be good to have a small example using new TYPO3 conditions.

Comment: like https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/9.5/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#request ?

Comment: Looks like this is really something people don't do. Really strange. I added now an extension parameter for the apiKey which can be changed by the administrator. This key has to match the key given by the client in the eID controller. I still think this should be done by Typo3 in some way and my solution is not really good but OK so far.